# Enforce minimum wait time for network connection

Tags: windows, group-policy, spanning-tree

We are currently using multiple HP ProCurve V1810-48G switches in our environment which we believe are causing issue with GPO based software installations. This problem surfaced after installing SSD drives into new laptops which seems to have sped up the boot processes enough to cause issues. We cannot reproduce this issue using HDD's.

It feels like the issue is related to Spanning Tree support. The computer appears to be making the connection long enough to satisfy the "wait for network" condition, but is being disconnected prior processing the GPOs and contacting the file share. joeqwerty commented that the root solution is to turn on PortFast or the equivalent, but this setting is non-configurable on the V1810.

I had found information on modifying "GpNetworkStartTimeoutPolicyValue" to specify a wait time before continuing to boot, however as soon as the network is detected the Timeout expires and booting continues. Modifying this value has no effect in testing. I tried inserting a startup script to ping localhost for a set amount of time to induce a delay as suggested in other places online, but that method also did not have the intended effect.

It seems the simplest solution is to upgrade the switches to a model that has this feature exposed but at this time that is not an option I have available.

Does anyone know of a workaround that could force the boot process to wait for the duration timeout even if the network is detected briefly?

Comment: Why not deal with the root of the problem and enable portfast (or the equivalent) on the applicable switch ports?

Comment: We had a ticket open with HP for a few months, figured they might suggest that, but I'll check into that.

Comment: Which model of HP switches are you using? ProCurve? 3COM? we may be able to assist more if you give some specifics

Comment: ProCurve V1810-48G's out on the floor connecting back into a Sonicwall NSA 3600. Come of the procurves are cascaded due to layout. After the procurves some also have consumer 8 port switches, though the presence of these seems to be of no importance

Comment: @joeqwerty There does not appear to be a featured labeled as 'portfast' on this device.

Comment: Those 1810 switches are not the most manageable switches. From what I recall, those are "smart managed" and have no real CLI. You can disable loop protection on those ports (or on the whole switch) but that will effectively negate the usefulness of spanning tree.

Comment: The portfast option on these models appears to be called admin-edge-port and is not available to configure on the V1810. Given that the option I need is not configurable, does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon**

It would be under: **Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates\System\Logon**

Please note that it will slow down the login process.

References:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg486839.aspx
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305293

Comment: We do have that setting enabled to resolve script processing issues, unfortunately that seems to function in the same manner as the GpNetworkStartTimeoutPolicyValue registry setting.  Once the initial network connection is made the waiting stops, but the connection is dropped shortly after the initial connection for about 15-20 seconds.

Comment: It appears this feature does not work in environments with processing policy set to asynchronous. I recall we set it that way for the speed benefits, but I'll investigate that further having found that info.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, the underlying problem is still present, with any kind of switches. There's no need to fiddle with the hosts' IP stacks though.

Instead of meddling with the symptoms, you should solve the root problem:

When you activate a spanning tree protocol on a managed switch, any switch port linking up goes through the *listening state* by default, where it doesn't forward any frames yet. This state is to guarantee that a new bridge/switch is incorporated into the spanning tree before actually allowing traffic.

On end-node ports that behavior often causes problems with DHCP, especially with host booting up fast. On those ports you should always activate the *admin-edge-port* option (*portfast* on Cisco gear), so the port skips the listening state and starts up in the forwarding state right away.

On the 1810v2 series, use *Switching → Spanning Tree → Spanning Tree Port Settings → Admin-Edge → Edge*. On Procurve switches, it's  `spanning-tree <port> admin-edge-port`.

*Auto Edge* is not the same and doesn't solve your problem, as it only activates edge mode *after* BPDUs fail to be received.